# calling class method (with constructors) without object instantiation in php

Tags: php, class, constructor, methods, instantiation

Ive looked and tried but I can't find an answer.

In PHP, is it possible to call a class' member function (when that class requires a constructor to receive parameters) without instantiating it as an object?

A code example (which gives errors):

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $end="";

    function __construct($value) {
        $this->end=$value;
    }

    public function alert($value) {
        echo $value." ".$this->end;
    }
}

//this works:
$example=new Test("world");
$example->alert("hello");

//this does not work:
echo Test("world")::alert("hello");

?>
```

Comment: I thought echo Test::__construct("world")::alert("hello"); might work but it does not, sigh

Comment: making alert() to a static function will do the job.

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunately PHP doesn't have support to do this, but you are a creative and look guy :D

You can use an "factory", sample:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
   private $__aaa = null;

   public function __construct($aaa)
   {
      $this->__aaa = $aaa;
   }

   public static function factory($aaa)
   {
      return new Foo($aaa);
   }

   public function doX()
   {
      return $this->__aaa * 2;
   }
}

Foo::factory(10)->doX();   // outputs 20
```

Comment: I think won't work. As you cannot reference $this without making any object.

Comment: @SirajAlam it does make an object - look at the `new Foo` line...

Answer (score 13):

Just do this (in PHP >= 5.4):

```
$t = (new Test("Hello"))->foo("world");
```

Answer (score 2):

I, too, was looking for a one-liner to accomplish this as part of a single expression for converting dates from one format to another.  I like doing this in a single line of code because it is a single logical operation.  So, this is a little cryptic, but it lets you instantiate and use a date object within a single line:

```
$newDateString = ($d = new DateTime('2011-08-30') ? $d->format('F d, Y') : '');
```

Another way to one-line the conversion of date strings from one format to another is to use a helper function to manage the OO parts of the code:

```
function convertDate($oldDateString,$newDateFormatString) {
    $d = new DateTime($oldDateString);
    return $d->format($newDateFormatString);
}

$myNewDate = convertDate($myOldDate,'F d, Y');
```

I think the object oriented approach is cool and necessary, but it can sometimes be tedious, requiring too many steps to accomplish simple operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call an instance-level method without an instance. Your syntax:

> ```
> echo Test("world")::alert("hello");
> ```

doesn't make a lot of sense. Either you're creating an inline instance and discarding it immediately or the `alert()` method has no implicit `this` instance.

Assuming:

```
class Test {
  public function __construct($message) {
    $this->message = $message;
  }

  public function foo($message) {
    echo "$this->message $message";
  }
}
```

you can do:

```
$t = new Test("Hello");
$t->foo("world");
```

but PHP syntax doesn't allow:

```
new Test("Hello")->foo("world");
```

which would otherwise be the equivalent. There are a few examples of this in PHP (eg using array indexing on a function return). That's just the way it is.

Comment: i am creating an inline instance and discarding it immediately. i dont see why i need to allocate a variable to this process... is that just the way PHP/OOP is?

Answer (score 1):

```
// this does not work:
echo Test("world")::alert("hello");

// works, as you are calling not to an object of the class, but to its namespace
echo Test::alert("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can do a

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php

reflect your class and trigger the new instance without constructor.

Here a sample code:

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $end="";

    function __construct($value) {
        $this->end=$value;
    }

    public function alert($value) {
        echo $value." ".$this->end;
    }

    public function end($value) {

        $this->end = $value;        

        return $this; // return Test object so that you can chain to other function method.
    }
}

// Solution #1:
// reflect your class.
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass('Test');

// Then create a new instance without Constructor.
// This will ignore the constructor BUT it will create a new instance of class Test.
$say = $reflector->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

// use end method that will return the Test object, then you can chain the alert()
$say->end('World!')->alert("Hello"); // output: Hello World!

?>
```