# PHP constructor not called

Tags: php, class, constructor

I have problem, can i call constructor without create 'new class()' ? Or you maybe have another way for this :

```
<?php

class a
{
    public static $hello;

    public function say()
    {
        return self::$hello;
    }

}

class b extends a
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$hello = 'hello world';
    }
}


echo b::say();

?>
```

I have try with :

```
$b = new b();
echo $b->say();
```

And it's work. But i want to use `b::say();`

Can help me?

Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you want to call a constructor without instantiating the class? Given that this is the purpose of a constructor in the first place... if you want to work purely with static methods, then don't use the constructor to set static properties

Comment: @MarkBaker because i will make a many class in different file with different value of $hello variable. so i just call like b::say(); c::say(); etc.
it's not real code in my project, but the logic is like that for solve my problem. sorry, my english not good. thank you!

Comment: If you're making many identical classes, just with different values of $hello, then I think you've misunderstood what OO is all about

Comment: Answered the question and worked :) Hope I could help you @kresek

Answer (score 1):

Check out this. Is this good for you?

```
<?php

class a {
    public static $hello;

    public static function say() {
        return self::$hello;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public function __construct() {
        self::$hello = 'hello world';
    }

    public static function factory() {
        return new b();
    }
}

echo b::factory()->say();

?>
```

Actually I couldn't find a way to do this without calling constructor. This is how the workaround looks like. `factory` is just a name. you can rename it.

[calling class method (with constructors) without object instantiation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098881/calling-class-method-with-constructors-without-object-instantiation-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll try it. Maybe i can change to 'b::say()->factory();'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible just make the say() function static like this :

```
public static function say()
{
    return self::$hello;
}
```

Declaring class methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.

This example looks to me like late static binding. So try changing that `return self::$hello;` into `return static::$hello;`

Comment: I tried this as I was trying to answer and for me it displays nothing?

Comment: because $hello does not hold anything.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. i've try before, but not work.

Comment: Read more about static. To explain in simple word, calling a static function it's like calling a new instantiation without a constructor so that $hello variable does not have any value.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked: *"can i call constructor without create 'new class()' ?"*
The answer: No.

> ... Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each
>   newly-created object

You have requested *"But i want to use `b::say();`"*
`b::say();` - is call of static method.
You can't override non-static parent method to static. But you can restructure your base class `class a` to make `say()` method static.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answer. Yes, my question is like that. But not must call a constructor. I search for another way. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class a
{
  public static $hello;

public static function say()
{
  return self::$hello;
}

}

class b extends a
{
public function __construct()
  {
      self::$hello = 'hello world';
  }
}
```

The thing that you were missing was you needed to add your content to your `new class` method. - Just call it like so:

```
$b = new b('Some words');
echo $b->say();
```

When calling a `new class` **and using a constructor** - You will want to add the content in the paramaters for the new class you are making.

It acts as if you are calling the `__construct` function. - Calling `new class($a)` will call the `__construct($a)` function once making the object.

Hope that this helped a bit :)

Comment: Haven't tested the code yet, the `self::hello` might not work.

Comment: Nevermind removing it now. - I tested with the `$` and worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for answer, jek! But in my question, i no want to use $b = new b().  i want just call b::say(); :D i'll update why i want using like that.

Comment: Oh sure thing! Sorry about that :') It's not possible to do that with OOP using just static methods - Static methods are supposed to be called using parameter's in the proper way of using it. I haven't dwelled with this stuff before but I hope someone can help you out! :)