# Fatal error: Class 'Subject' not found. Am I calling the class wrong?

Tags: php

The OO PHP displays an error "Fatal error: Class 'Subject' not found " when I open browse.php file that calls the class Subject, the fatal error pops up, my guess is that I'm calling the class wrong.

initialize.php

```
require_once('browse.php');
require_once('class_Subject.php');
```

browse.php

```
$subject_array = Subject::find_all();
```

Comment: You load the class *after* you use it. This would be 1. Load browse.php and use `Subject`. Then, load the class Subject. Change the order of the requires.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using factory design pattern, you need:

`$Subject = new Subject();`

then you can call any functions like:

`$Subject->find_all()`

To write it more in the style that you're implying, you need to apply the factory design pattern. Checkout [calling class method (with constructors) without object instantiation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098881/calling-class-method-with-constructors-without-object-instantiation-in-php)

You need to show how your class is written to determine what kind of design pattern you are using, as this affects how you instantiate the class. This would make it easier to get help.